# Erro ao rodar o programa em python via terminal com python 2: "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

Tags: python, python-2.7

O programa deveria criar um arquivo mes/dia.dat, porém nada é criado e este erro me é retornado, onde podemos ver que o arquivo não está sendo criado com o comando file.open(). Segue o código do programa. Achei no stack algo sobre o programa não reconhecer o diretório em que estou rodando o programa, porém, mesmo depois de acrescentar "import os", não há resultados.

```
import os

ch=1
while ch != 0:
    print("###  Script rodando. Bem-vindo a inserção de dados.  ####\n\n")
    m = int(input('Insira o mes:'))
    d = int(input('Insira o dia:'))

    name = '{}/{}'.format(m,d)
    curpath = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

    #abrir o mes/dia.dat aqui
    file = open("%s.txt" %name, "w+")

    qt = int(input('Insira a quantidade de alunos presentes.'))
    for i in range(0,qt):
            nome = raw_input('Insira o nome do aluno:')
            course = raw_input('Insira o curso:')
            data = '{} {}'.format(nome,course)
            file.write(data)

    file.close()
    ch = int(input('Fim das opções.\nInsira 0 para fechar ou 1 para inserir dados em outro arquivo:'))
```

Comment: Antes de tudo no arquivo, coloque `print "programa iniciado com sucesso"` e poste o retorno.

Comment: Você ta usando python2 ou 3?

Comment: estou usando python2

Comment: Ele pode estar buscando no diretório raiz como a resposta abaixo diz, ou na verdade entendendo a "/" que separa o mes e o dia como sendo um diretório dentro de outro

Answer (score 1):

O erro esta na linha você define o nome do arquivo, quando você passa a `/` entre os mês e dia desse jeito `name = '{}/{}'.format(m,d)` ele entende que deve buscar uma pasta  no diretório raiz com o número do mês para gravar um arquivo com o nome do dia, que ficaria desse jeito `c:/seu/diretorio/raiz/mes/dia.txt`. Com isso ele explode esse erro, por não encontrar o diretório ou arquivo.

Minha sugestão seria definir o nome do arquivo sem a `/`, pode ser um `_` ou `-` ou qualquer outro caractere

por exemplo:

`name = '{}-{}'.format(m,d)`